# Php Sql Server Stored Procedure

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspProcessProfessionalPinRenewal]
 @processtype INT ,
 @SinglePinNumber NVARCHAR(12) = NULL,
 @operatorID INT,       
 @returnMessage NVARCHAR(35) OUTPUT

 AS
```

.....

```
$sqlExecSP   = "{CALL uspProcessProfessionalPinRenewal(?,?,?,?)}";
           //$sqlExecSP   = "{CALL uspStudentGrading(?, ?, ?)}";

            // Prepare stored procedure call with three parameters
            $sth = $db->getPdo()->prepare($sqlExecSP);

            $processtype=1;
            $SinglePinNumber=$pin;
            $operatorID=Auth::user()->BusinessEntityID;
            $retMessage="";


            // Bind parameter 1 as IN parameter
            // Be sure *not* to set a length to indicate it's an IN parameter

            $sth->bindParam(1, $processtype, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $sth->bindParam(2, $SinglePinNumber, PDO::PARAM_STR,12);
            $sth->bindParam(3, $operatorID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $sth->bindParam(4, $retMessage, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 35);


            // $sth->bindParam(4, $indexnumber, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 50);

           // dd($programcatid . ', ' . $programtypeid . ', ' . $voucherpin . ', ' . $applicationref);


            // Call the stored procedure

            // print "Executing stored procedure...\n";
            $res = $sth->execute();
```

Above is the header of my stored procedure and my php code to call it

But I get the error
SQLSTATE[22018]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '17GS08664006' to data type int.

Please help

Comment: Show us not the header but the body of your proc

Comment: What is the value '17GS08664006' ? Can we get that code. Its possibly just a convert error like your error says failed to convert to data type int

Comment: the error says it all. you send data with a wrong datatype to SP.

Comment: It seems to be SinglePinNumber. That is compared/joined to int

Comment: @Badiparmagi If he passed wrong parameter, the error would be "Error converting data type varchar to int." When it says "conversion failed" it's smth inside sp like SinglePinNumber + 100 where SinglePinNumber is nvarchar ad 100 is int

Comment: going through the stored procedure I realized i was assigning a string to an integer. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

going through the stored procedure I realized i was assigning a string to an integer. Thanks a lot